# Как обращаться к дочернему элементу в css?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Допустим есть такой код:

```
<div>
<p>Просто текст</p>
<p>Еще текст</p>
</div>
<p>Тут что-то написано</p>
<p>И тут что-то написано</p>
```

Как указать стили для тега 'p' который находится в теге 'div', не указывая класс и т. п. ?
Когда я учил css мне сказали, что можно написать

```
div p {
/*тут стили*/
}
```

Но на практике получается какой-то бред. Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Через селектор `>` :

```css
div>p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Просто текст</p>
<p>Еще текст</p>
</div>
<p>Тут что-то написано</p>
<p>И тут что-то написано</p>
```

хотя и без него нормально работает:

```css
div p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Просто текст</p>
<p>Еще текст</p>
</div>
<p>Тут что-то написано</p>
<p>И тут что-то написано</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вы укажете `div p`, то стиль будет применен ко всем `p` внутри `div`, независимо от степени вложенности.

```css
div p{
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Просто текст</p>
  <p>Еще текст</p>
  <section>
    <p>Опять текст</p>
  </section>
</div>
<p>Тут что-то написано</p>
<p>И тут что-то написано</p>
```

А если укажете `div>p`, то стиль будет применен, только к "прямым" дочерним элементам "первой степени вложенности", обратите внимание, тут для `p`, который внутри `section` стиль не применился, хотя он тоже внутри `div`, но он вложен еще в другой элемент

```css
div>p{
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Просто текст</p>
  <p>Еще текст</p>
  <section>
    <p>Опять текст</p>
  </section>
</div>
<p>Тут что-то написано</p>
<p>И тут что-то написано</p>
```